Getting “App Not Available” when attempting to download “X” from the macOS App Store
I'm using MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) w/ macOS 14.5 and I'm trying to follow these instructions:

How to use X for Mac

But when I try to open App store link:

https://apps.apple.com/app/id1482454543?mt=12

I get the following error:

I'm in U.S. region.

There isn’t one and hasn’t been one since 2023 acquisition of Twitter, the documentation, is incomplete or inaccurate

This is not really about computers or software within the criteria defined in the Help section. It's about an app's availability in an app store available over the web.
